# pushing new objects to array results in mutation of existing object

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, push

I am trying to create a `.forEach()` in which for every `user` object in `users`, certain properties of `user` are mapped then pushed to `players` array as new objects apart from eachother.

However in my attempt, all the results of `user` stack into one object. How can I make sure each `.push()` creates a new object for each `user`

**What I Want**

```
[
  {
    name: 'Johnny',
    id: '123456789',
    lives: 3
  },

  {
    name: 'Timmy',
    id: '987654321',
    lives: 3
  },
]
```

**What I Get**

```
[
  {
    name: [ 'Johnny', 'Timmy' ],
    id: [ '123456789', '987654321' ],
    lives: 3
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
let players = []
const users = {...}
                
users.forEach(user => {
   let username = user.map(user => user.username)
   let id = user.map(user => user.id)

   players.push({ name: username, id: id, lives: 3 })
})
                
console.log(players)
```

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple map call. I think you want something more like:

```js
const users = [
  { username: 'alice', id: 123 },
  { username: 'bob', id: 456 },  
]

const players = users.map(user => ({
  name: user.username,
  id: user.id,
  lives: 3
}))

console.log(players);
```